# Making WSO2 ESB Version 4.5.1 ready for production environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I would like to know is the WSO2 ESB Version 4.5.1 installation out of the box production ready in terms of configuration, If no, can someone give me some hints, would like to know what to turn off in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

All the WSO2 products are production compatible out-of-the-box in general. But if you are using with distributed setup you may need to setup server in clusters with backend-frontend separation. And also you may need to use [WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer](http://wso2.com/products/elastic-load-balancer/). And the default embedded H2 database will not be efficient and you may need to change to MySQL.

Anyway if you are using a small setup in production all of them may not needed.